# Deleting and keeping layout - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm trying to make a macro that will prompt the user to enter a cell range, and then to remove everything else in the sheet (including colors, border etc.). The cell range entered by the user must look the same as before and everything else should be as in a blank sheet.

I have tried something like this at first, but not sure how to finish it up. Hope you can help me.

```
Public Sub Removeformulas()


'Prompt user to select cell range to keep

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

rngrows = rng.Rows.Count
rngcols = rng.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To rngrows
    For j = 1 To rngcols
        celltocopy = Cells(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not copy the range that the user inputs to a new sheet and delete the old sheet? Seems much simpler

Comment: This is in line with the answer posted below, and works to an extend. However, if you do it like this, is it possible to keep the original column and row width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

---

```
Sub Clean()

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Rng = InputBox("input range, format A1:B5")

     Range(Rng).Copy
     oldname = ActiveSheet.Name
     Sheets.Add.Name = "Test"
     'Range(Rng).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

     With Range(Rng)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    Sheets(oldname).Delete

    Sheets("Test").Name = oldname
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It will create a new sheet called "Test" and paste the values there, then remove the old sheet and rename "Test" to whatever the old sheet was called.

Comment: This is very close to what i was looking for.  However, if the sizes of different cells have been altered, this is not kept when running your program. Is it possible to keep the widths and height of columns and rows?

Comment: @selfexplanatory try it now

Comment: @ Andreas I did find the solution for pasting the column widths. However, is there a similar command for the row height (which i will also need to keep). Furthermore, Images (such as company logo) which is part of the cell range needs also to be copied, which the program currently does not do.

Comment: There is no formula to keep height. I googled it and it seems you need to loop through the rows to get the heights. In your question you did not say anything about width, height or images. I do not think you can copy images in a range as they are not in the range, they are "floating".